# recyclerview opens wrong item after filtering list using search

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

This here is my **Menu Fragment**

```
public class MenuFragment extends Fragment {


    @BindView(R.id.rvMenu)
    RecyclerView rvMenu;
    @BindView(R.id.etSearch)
    EditText etSearch;
    @BindView(R.id.llNoDataFound)
    LinearLayout llNoDataFound;
    @BindView(R.id.llSearch)
    LinearLayout llSearch;
    RestaurantDatabase restaurantDatabase;
    List<ItemTable> itemTableList;
    ItemListAdapter itemListAdapter;
    MySharedPreference mySharedPreference;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menu, container, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, root);
        initAll();
        return root;
    }


    private void initAll() {

        restaurantDatabase = RestaurantDatabase.getRestaurantDatabase(getContext());
        mySharedPreference = new MySharedPreference(getContext());
        itemTableList = new ArrayList<>();
        itemListAdapter = new ItemListAdapter(getContext(), itemTableList, position -> {
            ItemTable itemTable = itemTableList.get(position);
            Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), AddMenuActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("data", itemTable);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 100);
        });
        rvMenu.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 2));
        rvMenu.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

        rvMenu.setAdapter(itemListAdapter);

        ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(simpleCallback);
        itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(rvMenu);
        getDataFromApi();

        etSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                    /*
                    This method is called to notify you that, within s, the count characters beginning at the start are about to be replaced by new text with length after.
                    */
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                     /*
                    This method is called to notify you that, within s, the count characters beginning at the start have just replaced old text that had length before.
                    */
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                itemListAdapter.getFilter().filter(editable.toString());
            }
        });

    }

    ItemTable deletedItem = null;

    ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback simpleCallback = new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
        @Override
        public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {

            int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
            switch (direction) {
                case ItemTouchHelper.LEFT:
                    direction(position);
                    break;
                case ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT:
                    direction(position);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        private void direction(int position) {
            deleteDataFromLocalDatabase(position);
            deletedItem = itemTableList.get(position);
            undoMethod(deletedItem, position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildDraw(@NonNull Canvas c, @NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY, int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {

            new RecyclerViewSwipeDecorator.Builder(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive)
                    .addBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.gray))
                    .addActionIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_delete_outline_24)
                    .create()
                    .decorate();

            super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
        }
    };

    public void undoMethod(ItemTable deletedItem, int position) {
        Snackbar.make(rvMenu, "" + deletedItem.getItemName() + " is deleted Successfully", BaseTransientBottomBar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("Undo", view -> {
                    itemTableList.add(position, deletedItem);
                    itemListAdapter.notifyItemChanged(position);
                    try {
                        Thread thread = new Thread() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Looper.prepare();

                                /*
                                do In background
                                * */
                                ItemTable itemTable;
                                try {
                                    itemTable = new ItemTable(deletedItem.getItemName(), deletedItem.getItemImage(), deletedItem.getItemPrice(),mySharedPreference.getrdRestaurantName());
                                } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                                    itemTable = new ItemTable(deletedItem.getItemName(), deletedItem.getItemImage(), 0,mySharedPreference.getrdRestaurantName());
                                }

                                Long aLong = restaurantDatabase.getItemDao().insertItemTable(itemTable);

                                final Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {

                                        /*
                                        post background
                                        * */
                                        if (aLong > 0) {
                                            getDataFromApi();
                                        } else {
                                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Insert Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }
                                        handler.removeCallbacks(this);


                                    }
                                }, 0000);

                                Looper.loop();
                            }
                        };
                        thread.start();

                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        Log.e("error =>", "" + ex.getMessage());
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 100 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            getDataFromApi();
        }
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.fbtnAdd)
    public void onbtnAddClick() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), AddMenuActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 100);
        getActivity().overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_up,
                R.anim.slide_down);
    }

    public void getDataFromApi() {
        try {
            Thread thread = new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Looper.prepare();

                    /*
                    do In background
                    * */
                    List<ItemTable> itemTables = restaurantDatabase.getItemDao().fetchAllItemTableData(mySharedPreference.getrdRestaurantName());

                    final Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                    handler.postDelayed(() -> {

                        /*
                        post background
                        * */
                        itemTableList.clear();
                        itemTableList.addAll(itemTables);
                        if (itemTableList.isEmpty()) {
                            mySharedPreference.setMenuSwipeValue(true);
                            llNoDataFound.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            llSearch.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        } else {
                            llNoDataFound.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            llSearch.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                        if (itemTableList.size() > 1) {
                            mySharedPreference.setMenuSwipeValue(false);
                        }
                        if (itemTableList.size() == 1 && mySharedPreference.getMenuSwipeValue()) {
                            showSwipeDialog();
                        }
                        itemListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                    }, 0000);

                    Looper.loop();
                }
            };
            thread.start();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e("ERROR =>", "" + ex.getMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void deleteDataFromLocalDatabase(int position) {
        try {
            Thread thread = new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Looper.prepare();

                    /*
                    do In background
                    * */
                    int delete = restaurantDatabase.getItemDao().deleteItemTableData(itemTableList.get(position));
                    Boolean aBoolean;
                    if (delete > 0) {
                        aBoolean = true;
                    } else {
                        aBoolean = false;
                    }

                    final Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            /*
                            post background
                            * */
                            if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(aBoolean)) {
                                getDataFromApi();
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Failed Delete Item", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }

                            handler.removeCallbacks(this);


                        }
                    }, 0000);

                    Looper.loop();
                }
            };
            thread.start();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e("ERROR =>", "" + ex.getMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void showSwipeDialog() {

        Dialog dialogSwipe = new Dialog(getActivity(), android.R.style.Theme_Dialog);
        dialogSwipe.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        dialogSwipe.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialogSwipe.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_swipe_left_right);


        dialogSwipe.show();
        dialogSwipe.setCancelable(false);

        TextView tvGotIt = (TextView) dialogSwipe.findViewById(R.id.tvGotIt);

        tvGotIt.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            dialogSwipe.dismiss();
            mySharedPreference.setMenuSwipeValue(false);
        });


    }

}
```

And this here is my **ItemListAdapter**

```
public class ItemListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemListAdapter.MyViewHolder> implements Filterable {

    List<ItemTable> itemTableList;
    List<ItemTable> filterableItemList;
    OnItemEditOrDeleteListener onItemEditOrDeleteListener;
    Context context;
    Random random;
    String[] colour;

    public interface OnItemEditOrDeleteListener {
        void onItemClicked(int position);
    }

    public ItemListAdapter(Context context, List<ItemTable> itemTableList, OnItemEditOrDeleteListener onItemEditOrDeleteListener) {
        colour = new String[]{"#F8E096", "#F8D9D7", "#FDE1E1", "#FDE4C0", "#FAD9CE", "#F6B1C9", "#E8FAD3", "#E3FBF9", "#F4DEF8", "#D9EDFD", "#D2D7F4", "#E6E5E5"};
        random = new Random();
        filterableItemList = itemTableList;
        this.context = context;
        this.onItemEditOrDeleteListener = onItemEditOrDeleteListener;
        this.itemTableList = itemTableList;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
                String charsequence = charSequence.toString();
                if (charsequence.isEmpty()) {
                    filterableItemList = itemTableList;
                } else {
                    List<ItemTable> menuListModels = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (ItemTable row : itemTableList) {
                        if (row.getItemName().toLowerCase().contains(charsequence.toLowerCase())) {
                            menuListModels.add(row);
                        }
                    }
                    filterableItemList = menuListModels;
                }
                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                filterResults.values = filterableItemList;
                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
                filterableItemList = (ArrayList<ItemTable>) filterResults.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.menu_item_inflater, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        @BindView(R.id.tvMenuName)
        TextView tvMenuName;
        @BindView(R.id.tvMenuPrice)
        TextView tvMenuPrice;
        @BindView(R.id.ivMenuImage)
        CircleImageView ivMenuImage;
        @BindView(R.id.cvMenu)
        CardView cvMenu;

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ButterKnife.bind(this,itemView);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ItemTable data = filterableItemList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition());

        holder.tvMenuName.setText("" + data.getItemName());
        holder.tvMenuPrice.setText("€ " + data.getItemPrice());
        if (data.getItemImage() != null) {
            Glide.with(context)
                    .load(data.getItemImage())
                    .centerCrop()
                    .into(holder.ivMenuImage);
        } else {
            Glide.with(context)
                    .load(R.drawable.background)
                    .centerCrop()
                    .into(holder.ivMenuImage);
        }

        holder.cvMenu.setOnClickListener(view -> onItemEditOrDeleteListener.onItemClicked(holder.getAdapterPosition()));

        holder.cvMenu.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(colour[random.nextInt(colour.length - 1)]));

    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return filterableItemList.size();
    }
}
```

Basically, if I **don't** use the **search** filter the recycler **works** as intended, when I click an item it opens and displays the information of the item clicked.

**BUT** if I filter the list **using** the search filter and I click an item, it will open and display **wrong** information. **I noticed that the information that it opens when using the search filter is that it displays the info of the position of the item that was there before using the search filter.**

I searched and most probably the problem is somewhere in my adapter but I can't find the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
itemListAdapter = new ItemListAdapter(getContext(), itemTableList, position -> {
    ItemTable itemTable = itemTableList.get(position); //<<<< The error is here

});
```

The problem is that you get the clicked item from the original list in the fragment that you initially send to the adapter.

**Solution:**

Get the item from the filtered list, you can create a method in the adapter that returns the filtered list:

```
public List<ItemTable> getFilteredList() {
    return filterableItemList;
}
```

And replace:

```
ItemTable itemTable = itemTableList.get(position);
```

With:

```
ItemTable itemTable = itemListAdapter.getFilteredList().get(position);
```